# Render file text to html and be able to search its content

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm working on Angular 4 and I have a feature in application is render a file text with pure text (not parse to any structure) to html. I'm able to search a part of content on the text. Now I have a solution as the following:

**Solution 1:**

I would like to analyze the text, all text are wrapped in **`div` element**, that `div` contains multiple **paragraph elements `<p>`** content which separated by **newline (line-break)** in the file. Then go search keyword and to find out a `<p>` contains keyword, **styling CSS highlight** for specific text within `<p>` element. But I have googled but still not found any sample for this.

Maybe you will ask me why don't you parse all contents in one element tag. I think that it's more complicated for css styling and scrolling to position occurring keyword.

Therefore, I need some helps to find out for this case. Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Whether should I need to use `find` feature built-in of browser?

Comment: Hello... Are you familiar with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Hi @Zze, I don't know that why I have to use regex to parse HTML. I can manipulate the text by creating element (for example `<p>`) with sequence string. So what all I need is able to search a keyword to make only the keyword as highlight within `<p>`. Do you know what I mean?